# Know any great examples of CSS3 Transformations/animation for sorting/filtering group of items

Tags: animation, css, jquery-animate

We are building essentially a product/image sorter in pure CSS and js. The sorter will reorder products into different groups based on filtering and selecting. It needs to be ultra fast and smooth when moving/shifting products etc

Here is an example in flash of what I am talking about (click the links in the middle of the page to see animation):

http://dermalogica.com/us/products.html#/products/product-use

But I am looking for examples using Pure CSS3 transformation and/or JS that are as fast during animating and sorting as the example above.

Here is one example that I found using pure CSS that is sort of similar:

http://files.myopera.com/FataL/pres/pres.xml?1280852782

Know of any others?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this http://www.spritely.net/ has what you're asking, but you could give it a shot!

Comment: Nice find. Will def check it out.